# How long do I have to wait to update a snap?

Tags: package-management, firefox, snap

Since the latest version of Ubuntu I often get a message popping up in my system tray asking me to restart Firefox to receive updates.

Do I simply need to close and restart firefox to install these updates, or is there a period of time I need to wait before I start my browser?

Is there any way to know that this process has completed and it's okay to re-open?

I know there's a "snap refresh firefox" terminal command, but would like to not have to resort to that.

Comment: Don't have to wait. Firefox update will be installed on next launch.

Comment: I've found it doesn't always *update* on next launch (*snap* package) thus I close the `firefox` app, wait briefly for the kernel to remove all RAM (ie. clean up; I can detect this) then run `snap refresh` myself in terminal, after the upgrade has occurred I re-start the browser. This may not be necessary, but as I'm on the *development* release I prefer knowing things occur so I can detect & report issues.